# Splash regularly falls with status code 520

Tags: scrapy-splash

I am scraping website using scrapy-splash + lua script. Sometimes (randomly) scraping falls in random piece of code ( always in different piece) with such error:

```
 "status_code": 520, "client_ip": "...", "error": {"error": 520, "type": "CancelledError", "description": "Render is cancelled", "info": {"remaining": 59988.849385261536}}}
```

But it happens not very often, mostly I have correct result, but it's not allowed for me to have that error even very rarely.

in source code I see

```
        if timer is not None and timer.cancelled:
            ex = CancelledError(msg)
            return self._write_error(request, 520, ex)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't give me enough information what might be wrong. Any ideas/recommendations?

Comment: Running into this as well. No certainty here, but it looks like it might be a CloudFlare 520 being propagated due to a script that's causing the server to exceed its limits https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-520-web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error/44205. Not sure if there's a fix yet, but I'll echo back on here if I can get around it myself.